# warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, pointers, warnings, function-pointers

I'm completely stuck at this point. I have the following code:

```
typedef void    (*TPFN_ACC)(void); 
typedef char    (*TPFN_EVE)(void); 


typedef struct {
  int           idDestino;            
  char        * nombre;         
  TPFN_EVE      evento;         
  TPFN_ACC      accion;        
} TRANSICION;
```

And then I do this:

```
TRANSICION transiciones_Stopped[] = {
    {UPLEFT, "t_Stopped_to_Up_Left", ev_up_left, acc_up_left},
    {0, 0, 0, 0}
};
```

And I'm getting this warning:

```
warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
```

Could you please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you show the declaration of `ev_up_left` and `acc_up_left`? Either they are not visible or they are of different types.

Comment: void ev_up_left();
char acc_up_left();

Comment: ok see my answer, you swapped the two types.

Comment: OMG What a stupid mistake. Thanks man!!

Comment: @Aldridge1991 what do you mean by `typedef void (*TPFN_ACC)(void); `? I am beginner in `C`.

Comment: I defined a new type which is a pointer to a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this:

```
void ev_up_left();
char acc_up_left();
```

and in your `TRANSICION` structure, member `evento` of type `char (*)(void)` is initialized with `ev_up_left` of type `void (*)(void)`.

Same for member `accion` of type `void (*)(void)` initialized with `acc_up_left` of type `char (*)(void)`.

You probably swapped the two types / two structure members by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
typedef void    (*TPFN_ACC)(void); 
typedef char    (*TPFN_EVE)(void);
```

to

```
typedef void    (*TPFN_EVE)(void); 
typedef char    (*TPFN_ACC)(void);
```